# Powershell, Get-Unique blowing away already-unique, single objects

Tags: powershell

I'm gathering information from an xml file and processing it.  My queries are liberal in order to make sure I get all the possible elements I want.  As a result, it's possible to end up with duplicate elements in the result list (called `$components`).  I ran the result through `Sort-Object` and then `Get-Unique` to find all unique objects.  It is my understanding that one of each unique object should be left by `Get-Unique`.  But it's eliminating some of the already-unique objects (objects that have no duplicates in the original list).

Here is a simplified example.  Just paste this into PowerShell or save to ps1 file and run (output shown below):

```
$xmlDoc = [xml]@'
<root>
    <component Id='component1'>
        <regkey Id='regkey1'/>
    </component>
    <component Id='component2'>
        <file Id='file1' />
    </component>
</root>
'@

$files = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//file[@Id='file1']")
$regkeys = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//regkey[@Id='regkey1']")
$components = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//component[@Id='component1'] | //component[@Id='component2']")
$components += $regkeys | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'ParentNode'
$components | Sort-Object -Property 'Id'
Write-Host
$components | Sort-Object -Property 'Id' | Get-Unique
```

If you pasted into PowerShell, hit enter after that last line.

The output is like this:

```
PS C:\> $xmlDoc = [xml]@'
>> <root>
>>     <component Id='component1'>
>>         <regkey Id='regkey1'/>
>>     </component>
>>     <component Id='component2'>
>>         <file Id='file1' />
>>     </component>
>> </root>
>> '@
>>
PS C:\> $files = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//file[@Id='file1']")
PS C:\> $regkeys = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//regkey[@Id='regkey1']")
PS C:\> $components = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//component[@Id='component1'] | //component[@Id='component2
']")
PS C:\> $components += $regkeys | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'ParentNode'
PS C:\> $components | Sort-Object -Property 'Id'

Id                                                 regkey
--                                                 ------
component1                                         regkey
component1                                         regkey
component2


PS C:\> Write-Host

PS C:\> $components | Sort-Object -Property 'Id' | Get-Unique

Id                                                 regkey
--                                                 ------
component1                                         regkey


PS C:\>
```

Notice how `component2` disappears entirely once we pipe to `Get-Unique`.  Can anyone explain this and offer a fix that keeps the query scheme about the same?

**Edit**: I assumed it would use the `-eq` operator to see if the elements were references to the same object in memory.  If I manually try `-eq` it shows the correct objects being equal.  But Get-Unique seems to be doing something else.  If you add this code to the end of the above script it shows the object equivelance:

```
Write-Host
Write-Host "0: $($components[0].Id)"
Write-Host "1: $($components[1].Id)"
Write-Host "2: $($components[2].Id)"
Write-Host ("0 vs 1: " + ($components[0] -eq $components[1]))
Write-Host ("0 vs 2: " + ($components[0] -eq $components[2]))
Write-Host ("1 vs 2: " + ($components[1] -eq $components[2]))
```

The output (when run from script file):

```
0: component1
1: component2
2: component1
0 vs 1: False
0 vs 2: True
1 vs 2: False
```

Comment: Try the `-asstring` parameter.  From the technet article on Get-Unique - **Without this parameter, data is treated as an object, so when you submit a collection of objects of the same type to Get-Unique, such as a collection of files, it returns just one (the first)**

Comment: I tried -asstring with no luck. :/

Comment: I thought that the duplicate objects were actually two references to the same object in memory, and expected the comparison to be correct by default.  Evidently there's more going on.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `-unique` flag of `sort-object`. That gives the expected result for me:

```
$components | Sort-Object -Property 'Id' -Unique
```

Comment: This does seem to work for the example above, but when I try on my actual code then I get the opposite problem: the two copies both disappear and I'm left with only the one object that was unique in the original list.  I'm stumped.  Unfortunately I can't post my actual data (it's for work).  I don't think I'll have time to figure out what's different about my actual data vs the example above.

Comment: Oops, in my comment above this I'm not having the opposite problem.  I'm having the exact same problem. :P  Mixed up my objects.

Answer (score 2):

My gut feeling is that `Get-Unique` works well for scalar types like ints, strings, etc. (and maybe for set of well known types) and not for general objects, because there is no general rule that would decide whether the objects are equal or not.

Consider this example:

```
# getting unique string, works well
get-process | sort-object | select -expand processname | get-unique

# getting unique objects (PSObject), wrong result
get-process | sort-object | select -property processname | get-unique

# getting unique objects by their string representation, works well
get-process | sort-object | select -property processname | get-unique -asString

# what is the string representation?
[string](get-process | sort-object | select -property processname)[0]
#returns @{ProcessName=audiodg}
```

In your case string representation is:

```
[string]($components | Sort-Object -Property 'Id')[0]
# System.Xml.XmlElement
```

that's why even `-asString` parameter doesn't work